# Copy-SPSite destination database size issue

Tags: 2013, site-collection, restore, content-database, sql

I am using the **Copy-SPSite** command to copy a site collection to an other site collection (differente contentDB).
The source contentDB is around 50GB, but during the copy the size of the target content DB is more than 90GB, why?
I thought that the size of the copy had the same size of the source db.

Comment: destination DB contains any other site collection? at the end of command, size remains around 90GB? also check if their is free space in that DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra size was about the log. (generated during the copy precess, also if the recovery model was in simple mode).
After the copy, I shrank the contentDB and everything was fine. (the sizes were the same)